# SwiftUI application localized the wrong way on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, localization

I have a localized (in English and in French) iPhone app on the App Store and there's something I'm wondering for a while without being able to get a response.

As you can see on the image below (from Xcode), English is set as the `Development Language` but not as the `Base` one so I'm wondering what happens for a user in Spain (with a phone in Spanish) or in Germany (in German), etc? What language did he sees on the App Store?

[image: Localizations on Xcode]

Maybe I'm freaking out for nothing! But English as the `Base` and not the `Development Language` would be more logic? Unfortunately, I can't try it myself, making my phone in Spain/Spanish because I still get the French App Store.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The localization setting has nothing to do with the AppStore. It's related to the end user's device (or app-specific) region. You can add your localized files for any localization you need (by selecting the file and adding to the desired localization from the right pannel), but the default localization will always be English.

<sub>So don't worry</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Mojtaba! You're right because we set the App Store (screenshots and info) localizations directly on the App Store Connect. Damn, I'm so dumb! But just to be sure, if you download the app, you get the English version as a Spanish user (for example) because 1- there isn't a Spanish language and 2- the Development Language is like the Base one (even if it's empty)?

Comment: Users will get all languages available for your app. But they will see the app based on their device's region in their desired region. So: 1-> Yes, 2->Does'nt matter